# how to access data from an array placed inside an other array in php (codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
array (size=2)     //top array containg an other arrays
   0 => 
   array (size=2)   //array containing 2 index
     'content' => string '            The Lion King        ' (length=33)
     'slide_style' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
  array (size=2)
    'content' => string '      Current fruit : mana bhanya the =
    'slide_style' => string '' (length=0)
   2 => 
   array (size=2)
     'content' => string '      Current fruit : mana bhanya the king 
     'slide_style' => string '' (length=0)
```

i have that structure of array please tell me how i can access data in my view file

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your top array is $array.

You could loop through the array to access each inner array and its items:

```
foreach($array as $inner_array) {
    echo $inner_array['content'];
    echo $inner_array['slide_style'];
}
```

Or to access certain values of inner arrays directly without looping through the top array, you could do this:

```
echo $array[0]['content'];
echo $array[0]['slide_style'];
```

Within this second method, you can swap out the 0 for whichever inner array you want to access (0 being the first, 1 being the second and so on).

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: Does he not mean accessing the array in view file passed via controller?

Comment: i want to loop through the content  what can i do ??

Comment: @BenPlummer how to loop through the content??

Comment: I think there's been confusion as to whether you were accessing the data inside the controller (to pass to the view) or inside the view. If you already have the data available in the view, this is fine for outputting it :)

Comment: @sani If you want to loop through the content, the foreach loop I posted should work for you.

Comment: It should work for him since it is simplest answer to understand.

Comment: yeh its working but i want to print  the inner array . let say i want only 3rd index of outer array . so what i should be do?

Comment: let say i just want 6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'content' => string '      Current fruit : my name is yusra afzal .    ' (length=50)
      'slide_style' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: The 3rd index of the outer array must be an array itself in your case. You can't print an array as a string.

Comment: @sani The 3rd index would be accessed using $array[2] so to output the content value of that index you could do:

    echo $array[2]['content'];

Answer (score 0):

You pass that array as a second argument to `$this->load->view()`.

For example, you have a view page called `posts.php` and you pass data to it via controller like the following:

```
$data['posts'] = $this->post_model->getPosts();

$this->load->view('posts.php', $data);
```

and you access it in the view page `posts.php` like:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    // Here the other code goes ...
}
```

Like you mentioned in the comment, if you want to loop through the array, this is the code you might be looking for:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
   echo "<h2>{$post['title']}</h2>";
   echo "<p>{$post['description']}</p>";
}
```

This is how you access multi-dimensional array.

Hope you got it.

Comment: and i just want to loop through 2 arrays

Comment: You have multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Edited my answer. You can now have a look at it.

Comment: Loop out the title? Can you explain more precisely?

Comment: ok perumal .. i want to loop out the inner array . e.g i want array like that content[0]='my name is misbah'  content[2]='i want this ' content[3]='yes its work '

Comment: The example I posted is looping through outer array. But you can do the same with inner array but you cannot access it with index like $content[0] because you get a direct value of inner array when you loop through them.